# How To Replace id to title on URL codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me, i have a problem how to replace id with title

the first i have a link : `localhost/ci/index.php/product/productdetail/13`

```
product       = class

productdetail = function
```

and has been successful to the following steps using routes

```
localhost/ci/index.php/produk/13
```

but I still have not found to change the `id` to `title` on url

```
localhost/ci/index.php/product/bed-cover
```

``` 13`` to ```bed-cover`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make your title field unique in DB. After that you may query with title

```
$data['title'] = site_url('controller/method').'/'.$title_param
```

Or you may make your URL like this

```
 localhost/ci/index.php/product/productdetail/13/title
```

and then route as you want even hide the id (take 3rd uri segment and query)